# How to make a Silverlight page crawlable?

Tags: silverlight, seo

With [Navigation Framework](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2009/03/18/silverlight-3-whats-new-a-guide.aspx#nav), Silverlight becomes better suited for content pages. The next big thing would be to make it crawlable. I think one of the approaches could be abstracting the content in a database and using it within a Silverlight page for humans or returning a plain HTML for crawlers. Did anybody try to make their Silverlight pages crawlable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out : [Search Engine Optimization Techniques for Silverlight Applications](http://silverlight.net/learn/whitepapers/seo-for-silverlight/#search_engine_optimization_techniques_for_silverlight_applications) and [Static text under your Silverlight applications](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Silverlight-SEO.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I think making Silverlight crawlable is like trying to make a Flash page crawlable.  You need HTML for the crawler to see.  I'm sure that it's possible, but it would require quite a bit of work to implement.

It is however not a bad idea for SEO purposes.  As search engines don't like Silverlight or Flash.